# Is there a way to resize iframe videos using css?

Tags: video, embed

I have a blog with about 200 videos embeds (mostly using frames youtube embeds).

I'm switching designs of my wordpress theme from a 640 content area to 580. So I"m hoping there is a way I can use css to auto resize the videos. There are probably 200 videos, and I really hope I'm not going to have to manually resize all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please send a link to your website.

EDIT:

This will solve the issue:

```
 .content iframe { width:580px; height: 326px; } I
```

Comment: www.wpdallas.com/test username rick password 123abc   I've been using an iframe to embed the videos so that I could add the 'showinfo=0" at the end of the youtube link. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to add the showinfo=0 (so the youtube titles don't show up) to the link without using the iframe. (Also when you check out the site, go down about 3 videos. I've hand corrected some of the first ones.) Thanks.

Comment: try adding the following css:
.content iframe
{
    width:580px;
    height: 326px;
}

If for some reason it doesn't work try to change this to

.content iframe
{
    width:580px !important;
    height: 326px !important;
}

Comment: BAM... I added the !important one, and it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm. so now it's not working again. Strange. Can you tell what's going on now?

Comment: Now i'm here.. What's the issue? Where can I see the page after the changes?

Comment: BTW - which browser are you using?

Comment: They seem to be working now on firefox, etc.... however if you view it on a mobile device they aren't resizing for some reason....any thoughts?

Comment: Yes. Every browser has a different behavior when it comes to parsing and applying CSS rules so that's probably the issue. Which mobile device are you using?

Comment: I'm using an iPhone. It's supposed to be a response theme, and would resize when i'm on the iPhone, but it's not.

Comment: In which I can see the page after the CSS change?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? do you notice how the videos are stretched into where the side bar would be, and they don't look right...

Comment: In which address I can see it? The same address?

Answer (score 0):

this

`iframe {max-height:200px; max-width:305px;}`

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for blogger (solving some issues with Vines and Instagram videos):

```
.content iframe { width:100%; } 
.post-body iframe[src*=youtube] { width:100%; min-height:100%;}
```